# Swift deleting table view cell when timer expires

Tags: swift

I have tried hard to find a solution but I'm stuck. have a custom table view with timer in each cell. when the timer expires the cell should get deleted even if the cell is Offscreen it should get deleted and should not be displayed.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! iDealCell
    //        cell.SponsorLogo.image = UIImage(named: "back.png")!
    cell.SponsorName.text = iDeals[indexPath.row].SponsorName;
    cell.Distance.text = iDeals[indexPath.row].Distance;
    cell.Type.text = iDeals[indexPath.row].Type;
    cell.iDealTimer.font = UIFont(name: "DBLCDTempBlack", size: 18.0)

    onHourFromNow = NSDate(timeInterval: 10, sinceDate: timeNow)
    let TimeDiffInSec = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.Second, fromDate: timeNow, toDate: onHourFromNow, options: []).second
    cell.TimeDiffInSec = TimeDiffInSec
    cell.kickOffCountdown()
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

> in cell class, three functions to initialise and run the timer

```
func kickOffCountdown(){
    self.setCountDown()
    Timer.invalidate()
    Timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(iDealCell.setCountDown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)                     
}

func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Int) -> (String, String, String) {
    let hours = seconds / 3600
    let minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60
    let seconds = (seconds % 3600) % 60

    let hoursString = hours < 10 ? "0\(hours)" : "\(hours)"
    let minutesString = minutes < 10 ? "0\(minutes)" : "\(minutes)"
    let secondsString = seconds < 10 ? "0\(seconds)" : "\(seconds)"
    return (hoursString, minutesString, secondsString)
}

func setCountDown() {
    if(TimeDiffInSec > 0) {
        let (h,m,s) = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(TimeDiffInSec)
        self.iDealTimer.text = "\(h):\(m):\(s)"
        TimeDiffInSec = TimeDiffInSec - 1
    }
    else{
        self.iDealTimer.text = "EXPIRED"
        if let delegate = self.delegate {
            delegate.DeleteiDealID(1)
        }
        Timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreaciated

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: @appzYourLife Please see the edited Question

Comment: You want to delete the cell, or the row?  What happens if the cell is offscreen at the time the timer pops?

Comment: Yes, i want to delete the cell if time gets expired. And also for those off screen cells. if expire then cell should not be displayed  @vacawama .. Can you please help,, Am literally stuck at this point

Comment: No need to add timer inside table's cellForRowAtIndexPath you can manage this thing out side of table code because this will repeat every time and another problems will generate.

Comment: Can new cells be added to the table while old cells are "ticking"?

Comment: As it is a requirement to show timer like count down on each cell.. @Anand

Comment: you can give generate time for every then and compare with your cell expire time.

Comment: But is it possible if the cell is offscreen ?? @Anand

Comment: when you giving data to table cell in that condition you having all data inside your array or dictionary after time expiration need to check inside your array and compare generate and expire time then find that array count for cell , remove that object from array.

Comment: look at my edited answer

Comment: @Anand... Can u edit your answer with an example

Comment: when you getting data for new cell row. Can you explain me? @Haridas

Answer (score 0):

I think, this will be better way:

1. Inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` calculate (or fetch) time and add it's value to label in cell.
2. Remove timer from cell.
3. Add timer in main class (where tableView placed) in `viewDidAppear` (or inside block where you fetch data), that will every second call method, that check and remove expired objects (or you can apply filter) and fire `tableView.reloadData()` (or delete needed rows animated).
4. In `viewDidDisappear` invalidate timer.

Comment: can you please explain bit more

Comment: let me try and will get back to you

Comment: I read a comments, and I suggest you to rebuild all logic. I done same thing in one of my projects (except deletion).

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple thing whenever your time have been expire you can remove those values from your array of dictionary whatever you used for row count.

Simple thing here is your all table cell depends on your row count remover particular cell with by removing particular array object.

example :

```
if timerExpire == true {
        array.removeAtIndex(5)
        self.table.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: first, 20 data is loaded first

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky problem, because you want:

1. Table rows to be deleted even if they are offscreen at the time the timer pops.
2. New rows can be added while the old rows are "ticking".

The first point means that **you do not want the timer to be kept in the cell**.  It is the wrong place anyway, because cells get reused and you'd have a nightmare invalidating and restarting timers.

The second point means that the row number you want to delete at the time the timer is started could be different than the row number you delete when the timer pops.  You may start your timer for row `5` to be deleted in `5` seconds, but in the meantime row `4` gets deleted, making the former row `5` now row `4`.  When the former row `5`'s timer pops, row `4` needs to be deleted from the table.

Here is the approach I suggest:

1. Give each row in your table a unique ID.  This will just be a simple count that is maintained by your `UITableViewController` class.

   ```
   var nextID = 0
   ```
2. Maintain a list of active ID's that correspond to the rows that are currently in your table.  Add this property to your `UITableViewController`:

   ```
   var activeIDs = [Int]()
   ```
3. Add a dictionary to your table that maps a `NSTimer` to an ID.  Add this to your `UITableViewController`:

   ```
   var timerIDmap: [NSTimer: Int]()
   ```
4. When you create a new row in your table:

   ```
   let newID = nextID
   activeIDs.append(newID)
   nextID += 1
   ```
5. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, be sure to store the `ID` in a property of the cell.

   ```
   cell.cellID = activeIDs[indexPath.row]
   ```
6. When you create a timer, you need to store the timer and its corresponding cell ID in the `timerIDmap`.  Since you'll do this in the custom cell, the cell needs to have a weak reference to the tableViewController that holds it:

   ```
   // add this property to your cell
   weak var myTableVC: UITableViewController?
   ```

   and assign that property in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

   ```
   cell.myTableVC = self
   ```

   so that when you create the timer:

   ```
   let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimerInterval(...
   myTableVC?.timerIDmap[timer] = cellID
   ```
7. When your timer ticks, you need to decrement the time left on that timer.  That means the time left should also be kept in your model.  Add this dictionary to your `UITableViewController`:

   ```
   var timeLeft = [Int: Int]()  // maps CellID to time left
   ```

   that means that when you create the timer in the first place, you will store timeLeft in this dictionary

   ```
   myTableVC?.timeLeft[cellID] = 50  // some appropriate value
   ```

   OK, so now in your handleCountdown routine which should be implemented in your `UITableViewController`:

   ```
   func handleCountdown(timer: NSTimer) {
       let cellID = timerIDMap[timer]

       // find the current row corresponding to the cellID
       let row = activeIDs.indexOf(cellID)

       // decrement time left
       let timeRemaining = timeLeft[cellID] - 1
       timeLeft[cellID] = timeRemaining
       if timeRemaining == 0 {
           timer.invalidate

           timerIDmap[timer] = nil
           activeIDs.removeAtIndex(row)
           tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSIndexPath(row: row, section: 0),  withRowAnimation: ...

       } else {
           tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(NSIndexPath(row: row, section: 0), withRowAnimation: ...
       }
   }
   ```
8. This leaves very little work for your custom cell.  It should merely take the time left on the timer and format it for display.  In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, tell the cell how much time is left on the timer:

   ```
   cell.timeLeft = timeLeft[activeIDs[indexPath.row]]
   ```
9. The number of items in your table is the same as the number of items in `activeIDs`, so in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` return

   ```
   return activeIDs.count
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying these solutions but I dont think they are viable towards the goal. Just wanted to let people know. If you have found something that works or have found the same can you please let us know

Comment: This is not answering the question. Please add it to comments.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot or else I would

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I have come up with. Its not a perfect solution by any means however, it does solve the problem.

**In the viewcontroller:**

```
    func handleDate(timer: Timer) {


    DispatchQueue.main.async() {

        if self.posts.count < 1 {
            print("Empty")
            timer.invalidate()

        } else {

            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let date = Date()

            let componentsCurrent = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
            var components = DateComponents()

            components.hour = componentsCurrent.hour
            components.minute = componentsCurrent.minute
            components.second = componentsCurrent.second
            components.year = componentsCurrent.year
            components.month = componentsCurrent.month
            components.day = componentsCurrent.day
            let currentTime = calendar.date(from: components)!

            for post in self.posts {



                let cellID = post.postID
                let row = self.postsInFeed.index(of: cellID)

                let endDate = TimeInterval(post.time)



                if currentTime.timeIntervalSince1970 >= endDate {



                        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                        timer.invalidate()

                        print(post.postID)
                        print("Deleting tableview row")

                        self.postsInFeed.removeFirst()
                        self.posts.removeFirst()

                        let store: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["caption": post.caption, "mediaURL": post.imageUrl as Any, "likes": post.likes, "user_ID": FriendSystem.system.CURRENT_USER_ID, "time": post.time]

                        let firebasePost = FriendSystem().GROUP_REF.child(self.group.groupID).child("storage").child(post.postID)
                        firebasePost.setValue(store)

                        FriendSystem().GROUP_REF.child(self.group.groupID).child("posts").child(cellID).removeValue()

                        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: row!, section: 0)] , with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
                        self.tableView.endUpdates()
                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

**In the tableviewcell:**

```
func tick(timer: Timer) {

    guard let expiresAt = endDate else {
        return
    }
    let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)
    if let components = calendar?.components([.hour, .minute, .second], from: NSDate() as Date, to: expiresAt, options: []) {
        currentTime = formatDateComponents(components: components as NSDateComponents)
        self.timerLbl.text = currentTime

        if Date() >= endDate! {
            timer.invalidate()
        }

    }
}

func formatDateComponents(components: NSDateComponents) -> String {
    let hours = components.hour
    let minutes = components.minute
    let seconds = components.second

    return "\(hours):\(minutes):\(seconds)"
}
```