# Automatically Delete rows in a UITableView: Swift3

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView which contains rows of posts that are timestamped based on when they enter into my database. I want to have the posts (rows) of each cell automatically delete after a certain amount of time has passed. Currently this is what I have towards this goal:

```
func deletePost(timer: Timer) {
    for post in posts {
        let startTime = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(post.time))
        let date = Date()
        let endTime = startTime + 25
        let call = Calendar.current


        let componentsCurrent = call.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
        var components = DateComponents()

        components.hour = componentsCurrent.hour
        components.minute = componentsCurrent.minute
        components.second = componentsCurrent.second
        components.year = componentsCurrent.year
        components.month = componentsCurrent.month
        components.day = componentsCurrent.day

        let currentTime = call.date(from: components)!
        print(currentTime)
        print(" 2" , endTime)

        if  currentTime.timeIntervalSince1970 == endTime.timeIntervalSince1970 {
            timer.invalidate()
            print("ENDDDDD")
            posts.removeLast()
            tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
```

The problem I am seeing is that current date only records the date once but doesn't continue to update. I have looked through other posts regarding timers and I have implemented them however it has not worked within this context. I assume once I can get these variables to equal the other code will be straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

`cellForRowAt` is not the place for any kind of logic such as this. Its only purpose is to provide the requested cell. That's all.

What you want is to setup a timer, say once a minute (or some other appropriate timespan). When the timer goes off, scan your data source for rows that should be removed. Delete the appropriate values from the data source and update the table view accordingly using `deleteRows` passing in an array of `IndexPath` that correspond to the removed entries.

Comment: I am trying to implement this method. Would I create a seperate function to handle the timing or would It be within a tablieview function. In order to preserve the table that I present to the user I have to clear the array of posts each iteration. How can I still have access to the data I need outside of CellForRowAt

Comment: The timer would call a separate method that has nothing to do with the table view methods. The timer method would update the data used by the table view and then tell the table view to update.

Comment: I have what I believe to be a working set of code. It tracks current dateand time and also post deletion date time. The problem I am having is comparing the two dates. Ill add to the end of the post

Comment: I have also been looking at the bottom "idea" here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348067/swift-deleting-table-view-cell-when-timer-expires, however, I dont think this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your code will check if it's time to delete something only when your tableView is
`reloadingData();` .

```
    //That's not good, because `cellForRow` 
    //is called as many times as this method returns 
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return data.count;
    }
```

You should remove the data from your `array`, and then call `tableView.reloadData();`

To do that by specific time, you can :

```
timeToRemoveCell = 10:00;
```

and check this time in viewWillAppear.

or you can make a timer as rmaddy said.